# Report Builder: How to hide column headers so I don't have extra whitespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Here's what my report looks like now:
[image]

I'm trying to get my report to only display the "Old Skip A Pay Detail", "New Skip A Pay Detail", and "Account Number" columns only after I've expanded the Month item.
I've tried going into the visibility options, and hide with "Display can be toggled by this report item: Month", but I get this error.

"The tablix ‘Tablix9’ has ‘Month’ as a toggle item.  Toggle items must be text boxes that share the same scope as the hidden item or are in a scope that contains the hidden item, and cannot be contained within the current report item unless current grouping scope has a Parent."

Here's what I want the report to look like at first, then have the other columns appear after expanding the month item.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this link](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html) will help solve your problem.

Comment: Take a look at this, it describes the exact same issue. I've not tested it but it has an accepted answer
https://forums.asp.net/t/1429053.aspx?Hide+columns+when+Collapsed